# When i use estimator with same checkpoints to predict same file for several times, the predicted result varies

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, predict

I'm using textcnn model in estimator to classify some text. After i train the model, the trained model was stored in the form of  checkpoints. But when i try to predict the same test file with same checkpoints,the predicted result(porbalility and logits) varies slightly.

1. I have set the dropout_keep_prob=1 in dropout layer
2. checkpoints and test file remain the same one.
3. I have used the LoggingTensorHook to check the tensor values during the predict, two values begin to vary at the max_pool step(at least the conv values are same but i am not sure)

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def line_parser(line, vocab):
    def parse_content(record):
        items = record.decode().strip().split()
        cat = int(items[-1])
        tokens = items[:-1]
        token_length = len(tokens)
        if token_length > FLAGS.max_sequence_length:
            tokens = tokens[:FLAGS.max_sequence_length]
        if token_length < FLAGS.max_sequence_length:
            tokens += [FLAGS.pad_word]*(FLAGS.max_sequence_length-token_length)
        return [tokens, cat]

    result = tf.py_func(parse_content, [line], [tf.string, tf.int64])
    ids = vocab.lookup(result[0])
    ids = tf.cast(ids, tf.int64)
    ids = tf.reshape(ids, [FLAGS.max_sequence_length])
    label = tf.one_hot(result[1], FLAGS.num_classes, dtype=tf.int32)
    return [ids, label]


def predict_line_parser(line, vocab):
    def parse_content(record):
        feature = record.decode().strip()
        tokens = feature.split()
        token_length = len(tokens)
        if token_length > FLAGS.max_sequence_length:
            tokens = tokens[:FLAGS.max_sequence_length]
        if token_length < FLAGS.max_sequence_length:
            tokens += [FLAGS.pad_word]*(FLAGS.max_sequence_length-token_length)
        return [tokens]

    result = tf.py_func(parse_content, [line], [tf.string])
    ids = vocab.lookup(result[0])
    ids = tf.cast(ids, tf.int64)
    ids = tf.reshape(ids, [FLAGS.max_sequence_length])
    return ids


def train_input_fn(file_paths, batch_size):
    vocab = tf.contrib.lookup.index_table_from_file(FLAGS.vocab_path)
    dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(file_paths)
    dataset = dataset.map(lambda line: line_parser(line, vocab))
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(1000)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size).repeat()
    return dataset


def eval_input_fn(file_paths, batch_size):
    vocab = tf.contrib.lookup.index_table_from_file(FLAGS.vocab_path)
    dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(file_paths)
    dataset = dataset.map(lambda line: line_parser(line, vocab))
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size=batch_size)
    return dataset


def predict_input_fn(file_paths, batch_size):
    vocab = tf.contrib.lookup.index_table_from_file(FLAGS.vocab_path)
    dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(file_paths)
    dataset = dataset.map(lambda line:predict_line_parser(line, vocab))
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size=batch_size)
    return dataset


def create_model(features, params):
    # projection from sentence with id to embedding
    embedding_inputs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(params["embedding"], features)
    embedding_inputs = tf.expand_dims(embedding_inputs, axis=-1)
    l2_loss = tf.constant(0.0, name="l2_loss", dtype="float64")

    # convolutional layer and pooling layer
    pooled_outputs = list()
    for i, filter_size in enumerate(params["filter_sizes"]):
        with tf.name_scope("conv_{}".format(filter_size)):
            filter_shape = [filter_size, params["embedding_size"], 1, params["num_filters"]]
            W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(filter_shape, stddev=0.1, dtype="float64"), name="W")
            b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[params["num_filters"]], dtype="float64"), name="b")
            conv = tf.nn.conv2d(embedding_inputs, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="VALID", use_cudnn_on_gpu=True,
                                name="conv".format(filter_size))
            h = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.bias_add(conv, b), name="relu".format(filter_size))
            pooled = tf.nn.max_pool(
                h,
                ksize=[1, params["sequence_length"] - filter_size + 1, 1, 1],
                strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                padding="VALID",
                name="pool".format(filter_size)
            )
            pooled_outputs.append(pooled)

    # concatenate all feature vector
    number_filters_total = params["num_filters"] * len(params["filter_sizes"])
    h_pool = tf.concat(pooled_outputs, 3)
    h_pool_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool, [-1, number_filters_total])

    # dropout
    with tf.name_scope("dropout"):
        # h_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_pool_flat, params["dropout_keep_prob"])
        h_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_pool_flat, 1)

    # fully connected layer
    with tf.name_scope("output"):
        W = tf.Variable(
            tf.truncated_normal(shape=[number_filters_total, params["num_classes"]], stddev=0.1, dtype="float64"),
            name="W")
        b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[params["num_classes"]], dtype="float64"), name="b")
        l2_loss += tf.nn.l2_loss(W)
        l2_loss += tf.nn.l2_loss(b)
        logits = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(h_drop, W, b, name="scores")
    return logits, l2_loss


def model_fn_builder():
    def text_cnn_model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):
        logits, l2_loss = create_model(features, params)
        # train mode branch
        if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
            # loss
            with tf.name_scope("loss"):
                losses = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=labels, logits=logits)
                loss = tf.reduce_mean(losses) + params["l2_reg_lambda"] * l2_loss
            # optimizer function
            with tf.name_scope("optimizer"):
                optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(params["learning_rate"])
                grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss)
                train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
            return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)

        # eval mode branch
        if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL:
            # loss
            with tf.name_scope("loss"):
                losses = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=labels, logits=logits)
                loss = tf.reduce_mean(losses) + params["l2_reg_lambda"] * l2_loss

            # predictions
            with tf.name_scope("prediction"):
                probability = tf.nn.softmax(logits, axis=1, name="probability")
                pred = tf.argmax(probability, axis=1, name="predictions")

            # metrics
            with tf.name_scope("metrics"):
                accuracy = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=tf.argmax(labels, axis=1), predictions=pred)
                precision = tf.metrics.precision(labels=tf.argmax(labels, axis=1), predictions=pred)
                recall = tf.metrics.recall(labels=tf.argmax(labels, axis=1), predictions=pred)
                tf.summary.scalar("accuracy", accuracy[1])
                tf.summary.scalar("precision", precision[1])
                tf.summary.scalar("recall", recall[1])
                tf.summary.scalar("loss", loss)
                metrics = {"accuracy": accuracy, "precision": precision, "recall": recall}
                metric_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(
                    {"f1-score": 2 * precision[1] * recall[1] / (precision[1] + recall[1]), "precision": precision[1],
                     "recall": recall[1]}, every_n_iter=100)

            return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=metrics,
                                              evaluation_hooks=[metric_hook])

        # predict mode branch
        if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
            # predictions
            with tf.name_scope("prediction"):
                probability = tf.nn.softmax(logits, axis=1, name="probability")
                pred = tf.argmax(probability, axis=1, name="predictions")
                predictions = {
                    "class": pred,
                    "probability": probability,
                }
            return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, predictions=predictions)

    return text_cnn_model_fn
```

I expect the same output of twice predictions,but it varies like the following:
first time
0\0.02336916147480053
0\0.29461604884471243
0\0.04555523004833724
1\0.5450933830551228
0\0.042727966035733034
0\0.032764190484837884
0\0.11542703615898613
0\0.12662708812885717
0\0.01605587344580832
0\0.006454832043875243
second time
0\0.03389085341620636
0\0.31563690653966603
0\0.06185060165562852
1\0.5891016184323346
0\0.07184752629327144
0\0.04355442431024522
0\0.16290306166502935
0\0.17214872864042816
0\0.02437323886282706
0\0.0109889405648392

Comment: Please avoid adding postscripts (!) in the title (removed)...

Comment: tks for the editing, do you have some ideas about this error?

Comment: [A wall of code isn't helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/), and SO does *not* work by just throwing all our code as-is in a question.You should try to reproduce this in a minimal way using some public data - please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autually,i figured out this problem. The variety is resulted by  word embedding vectors which are generated randomly every time.